# Semidirect product of Diffeomorphism group and Weyl transformations

Tags: string-theory, diffeomorphism-invariance

This is more a mathematical question but in my string theory lecture we always divide in the Polyakov path integral by $$\mathrm{Diff}\ltimes \mathrm{Weyl}$$ and I was wondering why there is the semidirect product. Is there a simple argument for the semidirect product like for the Poincare group by the composition of two transformations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. A group element
   $$(f,\Omega)~\in~\mathrm{Diff}\ltimes \mathrm{Weyl}$$
   [acts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) from the right on a metric tensor $g$ as
   $$g.(f,\Omega)~=~f^{\ast}g\cdot \Omega$$ via [pullback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(differential_geometry)) and multiplication.
2. This leads to an outer [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) rule:
   $$(f_1,\Omega_1)\bullet (f_2,\Omega_2)~=~(f_1\circ f_2,\underbrace{\Omega_1\circ f_2}_{\equiv f_2^{\ast}\Omega_1}\cdot\Omega_2).$$

Comment: Qmechanic, this is your turf, maybe you know a quick answer. I just had a fleeting wild thought, I can't post a Q, it's too... fuzzy. Is the OP's semidirect product isomorphic to $SU(2)\ltimes\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: No, for starters the latter is only 6 dimensional while OP's group is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected I'm on the wrong path. I _love_ Physics.SO for this: while thinking on the answer I suddenly find myself on a possibly unexplored sidetrack. Even tho I much more often find myself in a roadside ditch, like this time :-))